# How to know what program a java process is running

Tags: java, process, taskmanager

I want to find out which application a java process is running for.

When I open a task manager, there are many java.exe processes listed there, but I have no idea what applications those java.exe are running for?

Comment: Try something like 'man ps'

Comment: @segfault Given the reference to java.exe, I don't think that'll work.